# Improving computational speed of Zonal Statistics on 150gb+ of raster tiles in R (terra package and vrt)

Tags: r, performance, gis, raster, terra

I'm working in R - I have a directory of raster (.tif) tiles at 60cm resolution, downloaded from Google Earth Engine (NAIP 2018 NDVI). (I am running my analysis on pc rather than in Google Earth Engine due to human subjects requirements of my polygon data.) The 52 tiles are each 1.2-3.8GB in size. I also have 982 polygons, for which I'm trying to calculate the zonal means from these rasters. My code (below) uses the terra package, and instead of mosaic-ing the tiles into a very large singular raster, I've chosen to create a VRT (virtual raster) file.

I am running this code on a Xeon Gold 6134 @ 3.2GHZ and have 128GB of ram. No matter what I set my terraOptions() to, R doesn't even come close to using a significant proportion of my processor or ram potential.

With this code, all 982 polygons will take 11.8 days to run. I would GREATLY appreciate if anyone could point me at specific tricks/tools that I may not have already tried (e.g., I've tried working with all the terraOptions, I've tried the raster package and the exact_extract package. The `exact_extract()` function won't work for me as I am using a SpatRaster/VRT and a `sf` polygon object as inputs - again to avoid mosaic-ing a very large singular raster.)

Thank you. (I apologize that I cannot share data, as its either too large or human subjects related...) Here is the un-looped code:

Edit: 52 tiles of 1.2-3.8GB EACH. My original quote of 150GB total directory size was incorrect as this was the compressed size in ArcGIS.

```
library(terra)

c <- "path/to directory of raster tiles"
v <- "path/new.vrt" # name of virtual raster

ras_lst <- list.files(c, full.names=T, pattern=".tif$")

terra::vrt(ras_lst, v, overwrite = T)

ras <- rast(v)

w <- vect("path to polygon shapefile")
w2 <- terra::project(w, terra::crs(ras)) # transform proj to same as raster tiles

e2 <-  terra::extract(ras, w2, fun="mean")

e2 # zonal mean value for 1 polygon (of 982)
```

show(ras) produces:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 212556, 247793, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 5.389892e-06, 5.389892e-06  (x, y)
extent      : -118.964, -117.6284, 33.68984, 34.8355  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source      : naip2018mos.vrt 
name        : naip2018mos
```

[image]

Comment: it would be helpful if  you showed `ras` (`show(ras)`) and include an example polygon that is similar to what you use. For example you could take the first polygon and use shift and rotate to anonymize it.

Comment: @RobertHijmans Thank you - I can add both show(ras) and polygon examples once im back at pc. This may be a uninformed question, but, is using a VRT for x in terra::extract(x, y,...)  ever going to be quicker than first mosaic-ing a very large singular spatRaster and then running the extract() on that? My quickest workflow at the moment seems to be using ArcGIS Pro to mosaic a single file >150GB, and then terra to extract the single spatRaster. I would prefer to conduct this all in R, but both using the VRT and conducting terra::mosaic() 1st, are significantly slower than ArcGIS as first step.

Comment: With `terra`  you could do `ras <- rast(v);  x <- writeRaster(ras, "file.tif") to create a single file; but I would also want to avoid that. There should be some performance penalty with VRTs, but some tweaking may be possible. It would also be useful to know how many tiles you have.

Comment: I have 52 tiles, each 1.2-3.5GB. And yes— that’s exactly what I’m trying to understand—how to reduce the performance penalty of using VRT as input for extract. (To see if I can get the speed closer to a workflow that includes ArcGIS.)

Comment: I would expect that what matters is how many tiles are covered by one polygon. Without specifics it is all guesswork.

Comment: I'm running the extraction for 982 polygons. Some polygons only cover one tile, while others may cover close to all 52. I have edited original post to include show(ras) and the polygon example.